# How to use multiple languages in android

Tags: android

I want to give my user an option to select his language and according to his selection i want to display language.
Can my android app support multiple languages. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it under your resource folder. For example, let's say you want to have language support for France. For such cases, you can do it by creating a folder res/values-fr/strings.xml. In addition, you can have a folder called res/drawables-fr, as well.

You can check out more on these sites.
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html
http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to is termed [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)